# request for member 'attribute' in 'object', which is of non-class type 'int'

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, object-oriented

I am trying to create a basic snake game using the arduino UNO along with the MAX72XX module, the LCD module and the analog joystick module. I am wanting to program my program using object orientated programming. I have no experience with C++ so I am struggling quite a bit to understand what the following error is trying to say to me: `request for member 'following_direction' in 'snake[0]', which is of non-class type 'int'`.Here is the full code:

```
#include "LedControl.h"
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LedControl lc=LedControl(12,10,11,1);
LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 13, 3, 5, 6, 7);


/*lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  // print the number of seconds since reset:
  lcd.print(millis() / 1000);*/

class Snake_body
{
  //private:




  public:

    int following_direction;
    int body_length[64];
    int x;
    int y;
    int previous_x;
    int previous_y;

    Snake_body(int x_value, int y_value) 
    {
      this->following_direction = 1;
      this->x = x_value;
      this->y = y_value;
      this->previous_y = y_value;
      this->previous_x = x_value;
    }
    /*void configure(int x_value, int y_value)
    {
      this->following_direction = 1;
      this->x = x_value;
      this->y = y_value;
      this->previous_y = y_value;
      this->previous_x = x_value;  
    }*/

};


class Power_up
{
  private:

  public:
    virtual void init() 
    {
      this->x = 0;
      this->y = 0;
    }

    int x;
    int y;
};

int snake[64];
int snakes_length;


Snake_body *snake_body;
Power_up *power_up;



void setup() {

  lcd.begin(16, 1);

  snakes_length = 1;

  for(int z = 1; z < 64; z++)
  {
  snake[z] = 0;
  }

  snake[0] = new Snake_body(0,0);
  //Snake_body snake[0] = new Snake_body();
  //snake[0].configure(0,0);
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  lc.shutdown(0,false);
  /* Set the brightness to a medium values */
  lc.setIntensity(0,8);
  /* and clear the display */
  lc.clearDisplay(0);

  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  power_up->x = random(0, 8);
  power_up->y = random(0, 8);
}

int snake_direction;


void loop() 
{
  int x_axis = analogRead(A0);
  int y_axis = analogRead(A1);
  int switcher = digitalRead(2);


   if(x_axis <= 400) //&& x < 7)
   {
     snake[0].following_direction = 0;
     //x += 1;
     //Serial.println("right");
   }


   else if(x_axis >= 600) //&& x > 0)
   {
     snake[0].following_direction = 1;
     //x -= 1;
     //Serial.println("left");
   }


   else if(y_axis <= 400) //&& y > 0)
   {
     snake[0].following_direction = 2;
     //y -= 1;
     //Serial.println("up");
   }


   else if(y_axis >= 600) //&& y < 7)
   {
     snake[0].following_direction = 3;
     //y += 1;
     //Serial.println("down");
   }





  if(snake[0].following_direction == 0 && snake[0].x < 7)
  {
    snake[0].previous_x = snake[0].x;
    snake[0].x += 1;
  }

  else if(snake[0].following_direction == 1 && snake[0].x > 0)
  {
    snake[0].previous_x = snake[0].x;
    snake[0].x -= 1;
  }

  else if(snake[0].following_direction == 2 && snake[0].y > 0)
  {
    snake[0].previous_y = snake[0].y;
    snake[0].y -= 1;
  }

  else if(snake[0].following_direction == 3 && snake[0].y < 7)
  {
    snake[0].previous_y = snake[0].y;
    snake[0].y += 1;
  }


  for(int a = 1; a < 64; a++)
  {
    if(snake[i] != 0)
    {

      snake[i].x = snake[i-1].previous_x;
      snake[i].y = snake[i-1].previous_y;    
    }
  }


  lc.setLed(0,power_up->x,power_up->y,true);
  for(int w = 0; w < 64; w++)
  {
    if(snake[w] != 0)
    {
      lc.setLed(0,snake[w].x,snake[w].y,true);  
    }
  }

  if(snake[0].x == power_up->x && snake[0].y == power_up->y)
  {
    power_up->x = random(0, 8);
    power_up->y = random(0, 8);


    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
      if(snake[i] == 0)
      {
         Snake_body *snake[i];

         //next_snake_body = new Snake_body();
         snake[i] = new Snake_body(snake[i-1].previous_x, snake[i-1].previous_y);
         //Snake_body next_snake_body;
         //snake[i].configure(snake[i-1].previous_x, snake[i-1].previous_y);
      }
    }
  }
  /*Serial.print("x: ");
  Serial.print(snake.x);
  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("y: ");
  Serial.print(snake.y);
  Serial.println();*/

  if(switcher == 0)
  {
    delay(50); 
  }
  else
  {
    delay(100); 
  }
  lc.clearDisplay(0);
}
```

the error is coming from this line here:

```
else if(snake[0].following_direction == 3 && snake[0].y < 7)
```

but I think it is also happening at all other lines of which are similar to this one.

I have tried replacing the `.` in `snake[0].following_direction` with a `->` instead but that just caused the error: `base operand of '-> ' is not a pointer`. I have experience programming in java python and a few others but not arduino C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed in that line:

```
else if(snake[0].following_direction == 3 && snake[0].y < 7)
```

And specifically in:

```
snake[0].following_direction
```

snake is defined as

```
int snake[64];
```

Thus `snake[0]` is of type `int`.
And you cannot request the member `following_direction` from type.
Since you make new instances with:

```
snake[0] = new Snake_body(0,0)
```

I assume `snake` should be an array of Snake_body.

So I suggest (at least) change the type to:

```
Snake_body snake[64];
```

Just as a side note, I think one instance of Snake_body can take up like 16 bytes, and you make 64 of them, this results in 1,024 bytes which is half the memory of an Arduino Uno. Also, sometimes a library takes up some space, so keep this in mind if you are intending to add more libraries/global variables or stack space.

**Update**

Also the following line seems wrong:

```
snake[0] = new Snake_body(0,0);
```

You already created 64 instances of Snake_body (and assigned to `snake`) after you do my change. So you do not need to do this yourself; actually you cannot, unless you create an array of POINTERS to `Snake_body`.

Comment: That is now so obvious that I see that. This was a silly mistake I did not see. Also you are 100% right in thinking that snake is an array of snake_body. I probably did it because I am used to doing arrays of integers. You are such a legend! Cheers!

Comment: One problem though, when I have done the line `Snake_body snake[64];`, it thinks it is a function

Comment: Can you add the line and exact error you get (it thinks it is a function, that's not enough for me to see what isi wrong)

Comment: I added an update.

Comment: Isn't `snake[64]` just an array that takes in snake objects. How would I exactly define `snake[0]` as a new snake object. `snake[0]` is supposed to be the front of the snake.

Comment: Would the pointer point at each snake object in the array?

Comment: You can write `snake[0] = new Snake_body(...)`, however, than you should declar the type as `Snake_body* snakes[64]';`, and keep a variable to show how many of the elements are filled/used.

Comment: I have already created a mechanism to see how many elements are in the list. That is where  `int snakes_length;` comes in.

Comment: Problem is now solved but the program is still having some work done on it. Its up to the point of what my question is about.

Comment: Yes that int variable is a good way to keep track (so it's like a stack object). If the solution helped you upvote it please, and if it solves your problem, also accept the answer (you can click next to the answer). Good luck with your game (I guess) and enjoy Arduino Stack Exchange.